# MasterPage in HTML5?

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages

I have couple of plain html5 pages in websites. all of them have header and footer is the same. I would like to use master page concept for these pages. like asp.net masterpage (but I dont want use asp.net masterpage concept here). Simple way that I want. It is IIS web server.

Is there any otherway in htm5 other than asp.net masterpage?

Comment: you could create the header/footer as user controls, and link them in to all of your pages. but that would make no sense at all when you can just use a master page to set the default layout of all pages in your site easily, with one extra attribute to your pages in the markup.

Comment: Or you can use MVC and use the template as the Main Layout

Comment: HTML5 doesn't care what server side technology you're using to generate it.  If you're using a particular server side technology, use that technology appropriately.

Comment: I think the OP is saying he's just making simple HTML5 pages without using ASP.NET. Converting them all to ASP.NET just to take advantage of master pages seems like a bit of overkill to me. Though, perhaps I've misunderstood.

Comment: @robertc .. Are you taking about _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: I'm saying if the way of getting master page type stuff on you server side technology is master pages, then use master pages.  HTML5 doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

HTML has no (serious) templating facilities. Use a template language. ASP.NET masterpages are one option. Others include [Template-Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) (Perl), [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) (Cross-language) and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) (PHP).

Comment: There's also ASP.Net MVC [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSI to import a header and footer file from another directory. You'll have to enable it in IIS as it's not enabled by default. You can read up on it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx).

Basically, once you have it enabled in IIS, you can do:

```
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/includes/header.htm"-->
```

To include the `header.htm` file from the `includes` folder in the root of your website at that point in your HTML.

**Edit**
Note: If you're using classic ASP, you can also pass variables into an included page which makes it handy for setting things like the <title> external to your template.